react grid layout custom component problem
I am using https://github.com/strml/react-grid-layout to create a layout of items with a toolbox but when I drop a component its added on the grid with default values
const ReactGridLayout = WidthProvider(RGL);

const NewForm = () => {
    const layoutStore = useLayoutStore();

    const onDrop = (layout, item, e) => {
        layoutStore.setIsDragging(false);
        console.log("Dropped tool:", e.dataTransfer.getData("text/plain"));
        if (item) {
            console.log("Dropped item:", item);

            const newLayout = [...layout];
            if (layoutStore.selectedTool === "Grid") {
                newLayout.push({i: "Grid", x: item.x, y: item.y, w: 3, h: 2});
            }
            if (layoutStore.selectedTool === "Textbox") {
                newLayout.push({i: "Textbox", x: item.x, y: item.y, w: 2, h: 3});
            }
            console.log("newşaylout:", newLayout);
            layoutStore.setLayout(newLayout);
            layoutStore.setSelectedTool(null);
        }
    };

    const handleLayoutChange = (layout) => {
        !layoutStore.isDragging && layoutStore.setLayout(layout);
    };

    return (
        <ReactGridLayout
            layout={layoutStore.layout}
            onLayoutChange={handleLayoutChange}
            cols={12}
            rowHeight={30}
            className="layout"
            onDrop={onDrop}
            isDroppable={true}
            compactType={null}
        >
            {layoutStore.layout.map((item, index) => (
                <div key={index} style={{border: "1px solid black", textAlign: "center"}}>
                    {item.i === Grid && (
                        <div key={index} style={{height: "100%", display: "flex", flexDirection: "column"}}>
                            <label>{item.i}</label>
                            <input type="text"/>
                        </div>
                    )}{item.i === Textbox && (
                    <Button key={index}>random</Button>
                )}
                </div>
            ))}
        </ReactGridLayout>
    );
};

export default NewForm;

this is a example of my code I try to render different components but its always add 1x1 box on the grid.
This is also my zustand store.
const useLayoutStore = create(
    persist(
        (set) => ({
            layout: [{i: "Grid", x: 0, y: 0, w: 1, h: 2},
                {i: "Textbox", x: 1, y: 0, w: 3, h: 2},
                {i: "Label", x: 4, y: 0, w: 1, h: 2},],
            selectedTool: null,
            isDragging: false,
            setLayout: (newLayout) => set({layout: newLayout}),
            setSelectedTool: (newTool) => set({selectedTool: newTool}),
            setIsDragging: (dragging) => set({isDragging: dragging}),
        }), {
            name: 'layout-store',
            getStorage: () => localStorage,
        }));

export default useLayoutStore;


When I use unique "i" value its solved also thx for the comment

{item.i === "Grid" && (
<div key={index} style={{height: "100%", display: "flex", flexDirection: "column"}}>
{item.i}


)}
{item.i === "Textbox" && (
<div key={index} style={{height: "100%", display: "flex", flexDirection: "column"}}>
random

)}

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
